# Given key get value from lookup table in *nix?

Tags: text-processing

I have a "lookup table" `table.txt` that has two columns

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
....
```

Now given a key `keyQ`, how can I get its value?

I tried

```
v=$(cat table.txt | awk '$1=="${key}" {echo $2}),
```

but it seems that this is not working with multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass awk the variable with the `-v` option

```
KEY=key2
awk -v key=${KEY} '$1==key { print $2 }' table.txt
```

If you want to exit after the first match you can use.

```
KEY=key2
awk -v key=${KEY} '$1==key { print $2; exit }' table.txt
```

Also I would recommend reading the [useless use of cat](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/useless-use-of-cat/).

Comment: `awk` also understands `awk '$1==key { print $2; exit }' key="${KEY}" table.txt`